# clearing input fields upon pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

After an a user presses enter inside an input field, I clear the value by `document.getElementById('text').value = "";`

As Im using a spacebars to iterate over an array, this displays multiple input fields with the same id of course `id='text'`

After typing in the first input field and pressing return key, the input field clear.

However, this is not the case for the proceeding inout fields. I understand `document.getElementById` only finds the *first* id.

How can I make this the input value is cleared for all input fields.

```
    'keydown #text': function(event, template) {
    if ((27 === event.which) || (13 === event.which)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('text').value = "";

    }
},
```

Comment: use class instead of id because the value of id must be unique within the HTML document.

Comment: so why are you not using the jquery lib?

Comment: I get the id by the context of 'this' which is captured by a keyup on the input element.  So which which standard attributes of input elements can be the same? Or shall I insert my own 'data' attribute, eg. data-sameidenifier

Comment: Also, I am using the attribute 'name' to identify which field in my object I want to edit. Is this good practice or shall I make a data attribute. eg. data-fieldname="details"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never ever use ID for multiple elements. ID is unique and it can only be present once in the HTML document. Use class instead or regular HTML element selector:

```
'keydown input[type="text"]': function(event, template) {
    if ((27 === event.which) || (13 === event.which)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //this should delete value from the input
        event.currentTarget.value = "";
    }
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

---

You can iterate over all the matches and clear their value.

```
$("[id='text']").each(function(){

    $(this).val("");

});
```

working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tq09kx7/), initially commented by @*abdullah*

**Recommendations**:

---

1. It is not good idea to use same id for multiple elements, id must be unique.
2. Use Jquery libary if you are including it `$("#id")` much simpler and neat than `document.getElementById("id")`

Comment: Thanks dude I updated my answer. You know I dont remember the time I was using same id for many inputs ( It is not good practice is the message) lol.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the event listener on the parent (the form for example). And instead of

```
document.getElementById('text').value = "";
```

by

```
var inputs = event.currentTarget.querySelector('input');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs , function(el, i){
    el.value = '';
});
```